# GCP Stackdriver alert on metric not absent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

there are some metrics in GCP's Stackdriver like f.e. `serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/exceeded` that appear when there is a problem and are absent (not 0) if there is no more problem.

The problem is I cannot set up alerting to auto-resolve, because when the problem is resolved data for this metric is absent.

How can I set up alerts to auto-resolve with these types of metrics?

[image: Metric]

Comment: Please have a look at this [feature report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119841714) at the Google Public Issue Tracker. Is that your case?

Comment: Yes! That is my case. Thanks.

Comment: Please accept/upvote my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no solution at the moment. Google Engineers are aware about this problem. You can join (use `+1` mark), comment and follow the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119841714) at the Google Public Issue Tracker to be updated of any changes.